# SQL - AND STATEMENT INSIDE RESULT CASE STATEMENT

Tags: sql, select, case, inner-join, conditional-statements

I want to execute some things like that

```
select * from table1
inner join table2 on table1.numero=table2.numero
 CASE WHEN table2.test = 'test'
THEN and  table2.test = table1.test END
```

i mean if i have table2.test = 'test' then table2.test = table1.test

thanks

Comment: Can you try to clarify what you're asking? Are you asking how to construct a conditional statement in SQL?

Comment: so you want your join statement to be table1.numero = table2.numero and table2.test = table1.test when table2.test = 'test'?  If table2.test does not equal test, then don't worry about it?

Comment: perhaps soem sample data and results would make it cleareer what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this ...

```
SELECT *
FROM 
    table1
     INNER JOIN 
    table2 ON 
        table1.numero=table2.numero AND
        ((Table2.Test = 'test' AND Table1.test = Table2.test) OR Table2.Test != 'test')
```

Comment: SELECT *
FROM 
    table1
     INNER JOIN 
    table2 ON 
        table1.numero=table2.numero AND
        ((Table2.Test = 'test' AND Table1.test = Table2.test))

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from table1
inner join table2 on table1.numero=table2.numero
and CASE WHEN table2.test = 'test' then table2.test else 1 end
= CASE WHEN table2.test = 'test' then table1.test else 1 end
```

using two case statements you can construct a when table2.test = test then table2.test=table1.test else 1=1.  I think thats what you are going for?

Comment: select * from table1
inner join table2 on table1.numero=table2.numero
and CASE WHEN table2.test = 'test' then table2.test else 1 end

Answer (score 0):

When i execute this query

```
select * from table1
inner join table2 on table1.numero=table2.numero
and CASE WHEN table2.test = 'test' then table2.test else 1 end
= CASE WHEN table2.test = 'test' then table1.test else 1 end
```

i have an error like

"Syntaxe incorrecte vers '='."

And for the second query, why we put a statement Or
 i think that's correct like :

```
SELECT *
FROM 
    table1
     INNER JOIN 
    table2 ON 
        table1.numero=table2.numero AND
        ((Table2.Test = 'test' AND Table1.test = Table2.test))
```

thenk you